# Same data repeated in list view

Tags: android, json, listview, baseadapter, getter-setter

I am new to android. I am developing an application in which i am getting some data from server in JSONArray format. I want to show the login time logout time and date on activity callled HistoryActivity and the latitude and longitude of on another activity i.e MapActivity in list view. I have a large JSONArray. The problem here is I am getting same date in the list view. Length of the array is correct only the data is repeated. How can I do this? I have tried alot. Here is my code.

```
  @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_history);
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
    toolbar.setTitle("History");
    clicklat=new ArrayList<String>();
    clicklong=new ArrayList<String>();
    dttime=new ArrayList<String>();
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.historyList);
    history = new ArrayList<Pojo>();
    new NetCheck().execute();
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

    ArrayList<String>clicklat= new ArrayList<String>(history.get(position).getLati());

    ArrayList<String>clicklong= new ArrayList<String>(history.get(position).getLongi());

    ArrayList<String>dttime= new ArrayList<String>(history.get(position).getDatetime());

    Intent i = new Intent(HistoryActivity.this, DetailsActivity.class);
    i.putStringArrayListExtra("clicklat", clicklat);
    i.putStringArrayListExtra("clicklong", clicklong);
    i.putStringArrayListExtra("clickdatetime", dttime);
    startActivity(i);
        }
    });

}


@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            finish();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}


private class NetCheck extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        nDialog = new ProgressDialog(HistoryActivity.this);
        nDialog.setMessage("Loading..");
        nDialog.setTitle("Please Wait");
        nDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        nDialog.setCancelable(false);
        nDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        nDialog.dismiss();
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        myAdapter = new HistoryAdapter(HistoryActivity.this, history);
        list.setAdapter(myAdapter);
        myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        try {

            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

            HttpPost httpRequest = new HttpPost(

                    "http://techie-web.com/demo/app/japp/getpoint");

            httpRequest.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
            SharedPreferences mmm = getSharedPreferences(
                    "MyPref", MODE_PRIVATE);

            String logempid = mmm.getString("id", null);

            JSONObject json = new JSONObject();

            json.put("empid", logempid);

            Log.e("JSON Object", json.toString());

            StringEntity se = new StringEntity(json.toString());

            se.setContentEncoding("UTF-8");
            se.setContentType("application/json");

            httpRequest.setEntity(se);
            HttpResponse httpRes = httpClient.execute(httpRequest);

            java.io.InputStream inputStream = httpRes.getEntity()
                    .getContent();
            InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(
                    inputStream);

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            inputStream.close();
            strServerResponse = sb.toString();
            Log.e("Server Response", "" + strServerResponse.toString());

            if (strServerResponse != null) {
                try {

                    JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(strServerResponse);

                    for (int k = 0; k < arr.length(); k++) {

                        JSONObject jsonObj1 = arr.getJSONObject(k);
                        Pojo pojo = new Pojo();
                        JSONArray subArrayLat = jsonObj1.getJSONArray("lati_long");
                        List<String> lati= new ArrayList<String>();
                        List<String> longi= new ArrayList<String>();
                        List<String> dateandtime= new ArrayList<String>();

                        for (int i = 0; i < subArrayLat.length(); i++) {
                            String lat = subArrayLat.getJSONObject(i).getString("Latitude").toString();
                            String loong = subArrayLat.getJSONObject(i).getString("Longitude").toString();
                            String datetimee = subArrayLat.getJSONObject(i).getString("date_time").toString();
                            lati.add(lat);
                            longi.add(loong);
                            dateandtime.add(datetimee);

                        }

                        pojo.setLati(lati);//adding latitude list
                        pojo.setLongi(longi); //adding longitude list
                        pojo.setDatetime(dateandtime);

                        String dateee = arr.getJSONObject(k).getString("login_date");
                        String timeeee = arr.getJSONObject(k).getString("login_time");
                        String timeeee2 = arr.getJSONObject(k).getString("logout_time");
                        pojo.setDate(dateee);
                        pojo.setLoginTime(timeeee);
                        pojo.setLogoutTime(timeeee2);

                        history.add(pojo);
                    }

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

And this my Adapter.

```
 public class HistoryAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Context activity;
TextView tv_date;
TextView tv_loginTime;
TextView tv_logoutTime;
ArrayList<Pojo> list;
private ArrayList<Pojo> arraylist = null;
public static LayoutInflater inflater;

public HistoryAdapter(Context a, ArrayList<Pojo> history) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    activity = a;
    list = history;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    this.arraylist = new ArrayList<Pojo>();
    this.arraylist.addAll(list);

}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return list.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return list.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
}
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    View v = convertView;
    if (convertView == null) {
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.history_item, parent, false);
    }

    final Pojo pojo = list.get(position);
    tv_date = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.historyDate);
    tv_loginTime = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.historyLoginTime);
    tv_logoutTime = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.historyLogoutTime);
    tv_date.setText(pojo.getDate());
    tv_loginTime.setText(pojo.getLoginTime());
    tv_logoutTime.setText(pojo.getLogoutTime());
    return v;

}
}
```

This is my json

```
  [{"login_time":"10:30:28","logout_time":"10:31:47","login_date":"2015-09-30","lati_long":[{"date_time":"2015:09:30 11:15:15","Latitude":"21.121776","Longitude":"79.047563"},{"date_time":"2015:09:30 11:15:52","Latitude":"21.121776","Longitude":"79.047563"},{"date_time":"2015:09:30 11:17:16","Latitude":"21.121776","Longitude":"79.047563"}]},{"login_time":"10:42:56","logout_time":"10:44:41","login_date":"2015-09-30","lati_long":[{"date_time":"2015:09:30 11:14:53","Latitude":"21.121776","Longitude":"79.047563"},{"date_time":"2015:09:30 11:15:01","Latitude":"21.121776","Longitude":"79.047563"},{"date_time":"2015:09:30 11:15:15","Latitude":"21.121776","Longitude":"79.047563"}]},{"login_time":"10:45:29","logout_time":"10:45:36","login_date":"2015-09-30","lati_long":[{"date_time":"2015:09:30 11:14:53","Latitude":"21.121776","Longitude":"79.047563"},{"date_time":"2015:09:30 11:15:01","Latitude":"21.121776","Longitude":"79.047563"}]}]
```

What is wrong here? Please help me.

Comment: call  history = new ArrayList<Pojo>(); before  history.add(pojo);

Comment: @Sree This shows only one item in list view

Comment: @Sree Clearing the history would just remove data. I think what you meant was newing it at the start of the AsyncTask? which doesnt change anything as they are done in order in onCreate anyway. @Pri, remove the `getItemId` I dont think it does what you think it does, you're never recycling views as you are telling the adapter each one is unique.

Comment: yes so you want to call history = new ArrayList<Pojo>(); before that for loop start

Comment: The async task is only being run once so wont change anything. Can you post a screenshot @Pri?

Comment: @RobVoisey yes , i am testing him, how much he is capable of solving issues, because know a days no one putting any effort to solve the issue buy them self

Comment: @RobVoisey How can I do this then?

Comment: @Pri you are getting this when you come back from another activity right? so please write  history = new ArrayList<Pojo>();  before starting that for loop, it will work

Comment: @Sree I have a button in  main activity. onclick of it i am getting this on HistoryActivity. I already have this before starting loop

Answer (score 0):

Always use `ViewHolder` when using `ListView`.Refer [this](http://antoine-merle.com/listview-optimisations-part-1-the-viewholder/)
 article.Rewrite your code using ViewHolder and check.

Comment: I have also tried using ViewHolder. Still not working

Answer (score 0):

please update your  getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) method like this

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

if (convertView == null) {
    LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.mytask_list_item, parent, false);
    tv_date = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.historyDate);
    convertView.setTag(R.id.historyDate, tv_date);

} else {
    tv_date = (TextView) convertView.getTag(R.id.histroyDate);
}
tv_date.setText("date");
}
```

do same for other textViews

Comment: What is mContext here?

Comment: it is Context type variable in your case it is .. Context activity;

Comment: it should work .. I think you should debug the code to know what data you are getting in your list ArrayList<Pojo> list;

Comment: you should not declare the pojo variable in your getView() method as final . please remove final from there. you can write like this list.get(position).getDate()

Comment: When you mark a variable as final, it means that you cannot assign a different object reference to that variable.

Comment: Is there any problem in settter and getter?

Comment: you have no need to declare pojo variable do like this list.get(position).getDate()  try this , if it does not work and list is containing the data in right format then post your code please

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91490/discussion-between-pri-and-awadesh).

Comment: yeah there may be the problem with your your JSON pojo class that's why i am saying to debug your code line by line to know what data you are getting